# Indy, How to know size of buffer needed?

Tags: delphi, buffer, indy

I have some problem when using Indy (**idTCPServer** component) to read data send by client, the data itself was a hex formatted so i can't use **AThread.Connection.ReadLn();** for that...

Here my sample data sended by client

```
24 24 00 11 12 34 56 FF FF FF FF 50 00 8B 9B 0D 0A
```

or

```
24 24 00 13 12 34 56 FF FF FF FF 90 02 00 0A 8F D4 0D 0A
```

**PS**: it's in bytes hexadecimal (data length may vary depend on command, at maximum **160 bytes**) which i can't get string representation since $00 translated to null (which mean i can't use ReadLn)

Here my sample code

```
procedure TfrmMain.IdTCPServerExecute(AThread: TIdPeerThread);
var
  Msg : Array[0..255] of Byte;
begin      
  AThread.connection.ReadBuffer(Msg,SizeOf(Msg));
  AThread.connection.WriteBuffer(Msg,MsgSize,true);
end;
```

this code will not work if client not send 255 byte data, while in my case data length can be vary, i have tried this, but no response outputted

```
procedure TfrmMain.IdTCPServerExecute(AThread: TIdPeerThread);
var
  Msg : Array of Byte;
  MsgSize : integer;
begin  
  MsgSize := AThread.connection.ReadInteger; //doesn't actually get packet length?
  SetLength(Msg, MsgSize);    
  AThread.connection.ReadBuffer(Msg,MsgSize);
  AThread.connection.WriteBuffer(Msg,MsgSize,true);
end;
```

so how exactly i can count how many byte data sended by client (packet length)? or could someone tell me the right code to read the data?

Comment: Why are you using raw TCP component?  What protocol are you trying to communicate over TCP?  That's a pretty salient point when asking such bit-level questions.

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is: *you can't*. TCP is a **stream** protocol, so there is no concept of a *message*. The data is received in chunks, whose sizes may (and will) differ from the actually sent buffers (the network stack is free to slice or merge the stream at will). 
You may built a message protocol on top of TCP, e.g. by starting the transmission, and every consequent message, by a "size field" and then waiting only for the bytes needed; you still need to check the actual size received and re-reading the rest if applicable.

The point is: *packet length* in the TCP world has *nothing* to do with the length of the sent messages. 
What `TIdTCPConnection` does behind all the `Read`-methods  is: 
reading *all* available data from the network stack, appending it into an internal input buffer and returning the requested *N* bytes from the beginning of the buffer, if available (waiting for next chunk, if not).

Comment: and how if i use AThread.connection.ReadStream? i'll add more description

Answer (score 3):

The 3rd and 4th bytes in the data you have shown specify the total size of the data being sent.  You were close to try `ReadInteger()`, but the way you used it includes the 1st and 2nd bytes, which is wrong. Try this instead:

```
procedure TfrmMain.IdTCPServerExecute(AThread: TIdPeerThread);
var
  Unknown: Smallint; // maybe a msg type?
  DataSize: Smallint;
  Data: Array of Byte;
begin
  Unknown := AThread.Connection.ReadSmallInt;
  DataSize := AThread.Connection.ReadSmallInt - 4;
  SetLength(Data, DataSize);
  AThread.Connection.ReadBuffer(Data[0], DataSize);
  //...
end;
```

Comment: could you explain this line "DataSize := AThread.Connection.ReadSmallInt - 4;"

Comment: The 3rd and 4th bytes consist of a 16-bit network-endian integer that species the TOTAL size of the packet.  That length includes the first 4 bytes.  So you have to retreive the length and then subtract 4 to get the length of the remaining payload.